# Is there a way to go back and run remaining code in a label after a conditional jump (assembly x86)?

Tags: assembly, x86

So I am currently learning assembly for a college course and I am curious if it is possible (specifically for a loop) to go back to a code label and run the rest of the loop after the jump was made?

For example, the program I am trying to write requires 10 numbers per line so I was wondering if I could get something like this to create a new line once 10 numbers are found but there are till more numbers to calculate:

```
    mov ECX, number
    find_primes:
    cmp col_number, 10
    jg new_line
    *Then come back here
        nested_loop:
        *fancy code that calculates prime numbers here*
    *prints prime number on the current line 
    loop outside_loop  ; starts all over again

    new_line:
    call CrLf
    *return back to current spot?*
```

I know its a rough psuedo code but hopefully it shows what I am trying to do. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Of course, use another jump, maybe unconditional.

Comment: Note that “in a label” doesn't make sense.  Labels don't contain anything.  They just mark placed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just jump back, because the stack remains untouched. But make sure to save the registers used by the `call CRLF`, either with [popa](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popa:popad)/[pusha](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pusha:pushad) or more specific `PUSH reg`/`POP reg` combinations.

```
  mov ECX, number
find_primes:
  cmp col_number, 10
  jg new_line
; Then come back here
return_label:
    nested_loop:
    *fancy code that calculates prime numbers here*
*prints prime number on the current line 
loop outside_loop  ; starts all over again

new_line:
; Save regs with PUSH 
call CrLf
; Restore regs with POP
*return back to current spot?*
JMP return_label
```

This would work for the first 10 numbers. But you only check if the count is greater than 10 with `cmp col_number, 10`. The eleventh element would also be followed by a new line. And so the 12th...

So you need another, a more refined approach.

One easy way is using a modulo operation with the [DIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) instructon whose function is

> Unsigned divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with result stored in EAX ← Quotient, EDX ← Remainder.

and returns the *remainder* in EDX. In code this could look like this:

```
mov ECX, number    ; ECX = current number
mov EBX, 10        ; every 10th line
find_primes:
  xor edx,edx      ; clear upper 32-bits of the 64-bit value in EDX:EAX
  mov eax, ecx     ; EDX:EAX contains number
  div ebx          ; divide EDX:EAX by 10
  cmp edx, 0       ; check if remainder in EDX is zero
  jne nested_loop  ; if not, skip CrLf code
  ; Save regs with PUSH 
  call CrLf
  ; Restore regs with POP
  ; Then come back here
  nested_loop:
    *fancy code that calculates prime numbers here*
*prints prime number on the current line 
loop outside_loop  ; starts all over again
```

This is somewhat pseudo code, but you should get the gist of the assembly part. Maybe you need to save the `EBX` register before the code and restore it afterwards. This depends on your environment.

Comment: Thanks! This made a lot of sense!

Comment: Ugh, don't actually use `div` inside your loop, use a counter that counts down toward 0, which you reset to 9 or 10 along with printing a CRLF.  So the code in the common case is just `dec ebx`/`jz handle_special_case` , then a `back_from_special_case:` label.  @CoryYeo: Like this asm FizzBuzz: [16-bit FizzBuzz in x86 NASM assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56896)  (or related: [x86-64 Assembly - Sum of multiples of 3 or 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253680))

Comment: Yes. That's another possiblity which is more assembly like and not like from C. Even easier would be breaking on every 8th element by testing `test ecx, 111b` for zero.